# javascript function works until it is moved into a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about placement of javascript.

The function nqi_search works fine when it lives outside of a.js file. 
It fails, without errors, if it is moved into  my1.js, before the jquery files, or into my2.js after the jquery files. I've had similar problems before. Are there rules about what can and cannot go into .js files, and the order of .js files?

nqi_search is called within the jQuery ready function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/my1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/my2.js"> </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function nqi_search (type, id_name, text_name)
{
    $(function() {
        function store_id( id ) {
            $( "#"+id_name ).val(id);
        }

        $( "#"+text_name ).autocomplete({
            source: "remote.php?f=nqi_search&t="+type,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                store_id( ui.item.id );
            }
        });
    }); 
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    nqi_search ("product_search", "product_id", "product_name");    


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nqi_search` uses `$(function()...` wrapper which is the same as `jQuery(document).ready...`. Since it's already being called from a ready() handler, it doesn't make much sense. Try removing the wrapper:

```
function nqi_search (type, id_name, text_name)
{
        function store_id( id ) {
            $( "#"+id_name ).val(id);
        }

        $( "#"+text_name ).autocomplete({
            source: "remote.php?f=nqi_search&t="+type,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                store_id( ui.item.id );
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: you are right that I should remove the wrapper, thanks. However it still doesn't work if I move it into it's own .js file that I include at the end of all the other ones.

Comment: I don't understand "doesn't work". Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order of the .js files that you include with the `<script>` tag is important.

It looks like your function is using jQuery, but you are including the `jquery.js` file after `my1.js`. You should probably include jQuery, and other libraries, before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Any valid JavaScript can go into a .js file, but the order you load them matters.  If you have functions that rely on jQuery, but you load jQuery last, you'll have errors that may not be reported by the browser.  It's a common requirement in programming - you can't rely on functions and values you haven't loaded yet.  You need jQuery to run your custom functions, so load jQuery first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the order matters. It is crucial!

Best practice is that ALL of your Javascript includes should be at the BOTTOM of your html file, just before the `</body>` tag. EG:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/my2.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Added: This will be a speedup for loading/first page display. But it also means that none of your `<script>` JS before the libraries are included can use them. The goal is to download all of the html, then the JS.

**Re why doesn't it work?**

Be sure not to include the `<script>` tags in the JS file. File should be:

```
function nqi_search (type, id_name, text_name)
{
$(function() {
    function store_id( id ) {
        $( "#"+id_name ).val(id);
    }

    $( "#"+text_name ).autocomplete({
        source: "remote.php?f=nqi_search&t="+type,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            store_id( ui.item.id );
        }
    });
}); 
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
nqi_search ("product_search", "product_id", "product_name");
});
```

Also note I added a semicolon after the close { of your first function.